# laravel blade old input

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm learning Laravel and I have a problem returning the old inputs to the form.

ERROR:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

ROUTES - all in the file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {

        return view('artigo');

        $artigo = \App\Comentario::find(2)->artigo;
        var_dump($artigo->title);

        $comentarios = \App\Artigo::find(1)->comentario;
        foreach($comentarios as $comentario){
            var_dump($comentario->body);
        }
    });

    Route::post('/', function(){
        $rules = array(
            'title'=>'required|max:10',
            'body'=>'required|max:4'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make($_POST,$rules);
        if($validator->fails())
            return Redirect::to('/')->withInput()->withErrors($validator->errors());

        return 'yooo';
    });

});
```

BLADE VIEW

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="/">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="titulo" value="{{ old('title') }}">
        <input type="text" name="body" placeholder="body">
        <input type="submit" value="go">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?

**ATENTION:** im not using sessions yet

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using version 5.2 this is might be because your requests are not utilising the sessions. In Laravel 5.2 Sessions are available only if you are using the `web` middleware.

You should include all routes using sessions within a [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups) group called `web` which is defined in `app/Http/Kernel.php` under `$middlewareGroups`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

    // Routes using sessions

});
```

Comment: i already cut and paste my route on  middleware group web and is the same.
i dont have sessions because im learning yet

Comment: Can you update the question with routes you have included.

Comment: You need to put the other get route inside the middleware as well.

Comment: why? i dont understand verywell this part of the routes inside middleware web, auth etc , why not outside? can you explain pls
new error , updated topic

Comment: If you look at the middleware group named web under the file I have mentioned in the answer you'll see that it is defined to use several middlewares for `web` group including `SessionStart`. So only routes defined inside web group will have access to sessions. If you do not like this you can add the session always by adding `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to `middleware` property of `app/Http/Kernel.php`

Comment: ok now is working i add {!! csrf_field() !!} after <form>
why i need csrf?

Comment: That behavior is also defined by a middleware `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,`

Comment: i dont get it on csrf but ty for the help